# RAILS: how to run specific task on rails backend based on a DB datetime record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to send birthday greeting messages to users. I thought to implement it via standalone program that may run in `crontab` but I would like to learn how it might be possible on `ruby on rails` without using a `crontab job`?

Comment: There are number of gems that help to solve such problems, for example: https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ruby (and therefore Rails) with the `whenever` gem. It's pretty simple in that you can create a simple script or task to check the db, and if the birthday is today, send out a mailer via Rails. Then using `whenever`, you stick that script in their `schedule.rb` file, saying to run it everyday at a certain time. Then you run the setup command, `whenever -i`, and that will automatically setup your crontab to run your Rails script that talks to your DB. It's super simple and leverages cron but with the ease of Ruby.

Here's an example of what it'd look like in `config/schedule.rb` I use:

```
every 1.day, at: '1:00am' do
  rake "task:send_letters", environment: 'production'
end

every 1.day, at: '3:45 am' do
  command "cat /dev/null > /home/deploy/cronlog.log", environment: 'production'
  runner "Billing.set_invoiced_amounts", environment: 'production'
end
```

Once you've run the setup command, take a look at `crontab -l`, you'll see the above translated to cron format perfectly while still invoking the right environments and settings needed.

The gem docs are pretty good for the most part.

https://github.com/javan/whenever

Answer (score 0):

For minimal setup of "cron-like" tasks in "core" rails, I created https://github.com/Ebbe/arask. It doesn't use crond.

Add `gem 'arask'` to your Gemfile, run `bundle install`, `rails generate arask:install` and `rails db:migrate`.

Now you can setup your tasks in the file config/initializers/arask.rb:

```
arask.create task: 'users:birthday_congrats', cron: '0 2 * * *' # At 02:00 every day
```

The tasks will automatically run if the server is running.